# How to open the Samsung native gallery without having an error toast?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-gallery

I want to open the phone's gallery using a button from my application. I'm using something like this:

```
goToGalleryButton.setOnClickListener {
  val intent = Intent()
  intent.action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
  intent.type = "image/*"
  intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
  startActivity(intent)
}
```

After pressing the button, a pop-up for choosing the desired application appears. If I choose the Google Photos application everything is good and I can see all the images and videos as I want, but if I choose the Samsung's gallery I get a toast with "Unsupported file" error message.

Something similar happens on Huawei devices on choosing the native gallery application.

Is there a way to avoid that error message when opening the native gallery app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if I choose the Samsung's gallery I get a toast with "Unsupported file" error message

Sure. Your `Intent` is broken:

- `ACTION_VIEW` takes a `Uri` of the content to be viewed — you are not including that
- `ACTION_VIEW` takes a concrete MIME type of that content — you are using a wildcard

You are assuming that the developers of apps capable of viewing images will "gracefully degrade" when they receive a flawed `Intent`. That happens to be the case for Google Photos, apparently. It will not be the case in general.

> I want to open the phone's gallery using a button from my application

I am interpreting this as meaning that you want to do the same thing as would happen if the user tapped the launcher icon for that app. If so:

- Create an `Intent` for `ACTION_MAIN` and `CATEGORY_LAUNCHER`
- Add [a selector `Intent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#setSelector(android.content.Intent)) to that one, where the selector will help constrain which apps are used for the chooser

Probably [`CATEGORY_APP_GALLERY`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#CATEGORY_APP_GALLERY) will be the right category to use for the selector `Intent`.

You can combine all of that [using `makeMainSelectorActivity()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#makeMainSelectorActivity(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)):

```kotlin
val intent = Intent.makeMainSelectorActivity(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, Intent.CATEGORY_APP_GALLERY)
  .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is really helpful. I found the intent category for gallery, but I was not careful enough to use it in `makeMainSelectorActivity` and I was getting an error _No Activity found to handle Intent_